# Eliminar valores específicos de columna o de todo el df en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una columna en mi df llamada 'price' que busco que sea una variable entera.
Lo que ocurre es que tiene algunos valores iguales a '?'

¿Cómo puedo hacer para eliminar solo los registros que posean el valor '?' y que quede un registro vacío ahí?
Es decir, reemplazar '?' por ''.

Gracias de antemano y espero se entienda.

```
*Ejemplo del df* (en 'horsepower' agregue otro de estos valores)
| symboling | horsepower | price |
|:--------- |:----------:| -----:|
| 3         |111         | 13495 |
| 3         |154         | 16500 |
| 1         |112         | ?     |
| 1         |?           | 16500 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El concepto de "vacío" en R está asociado al valor `NA`, un valor blanco no se considera ausencia de valor. Para reemplazar estos casos, hay varias formas, lo más básico podría ser:

##### Usar el `ifelse()`

```
df$price <- ifelse(df$price=="?", NA, df$price)
```

##### Reemplazando directamente los valores en cuestión

```
df$price[df$price=="?"] <- NA
```

También puedes aplicar esto en todas las columnas:

```
as.data.frame.list(lapply(df, FUN=function(x) {ifelse(x=="?", NA, x)}))
```

Comment: Tengo una consulta más al respecto. Y si yo quisiera eliminar todos los valores "?" que existen en todo df y no solo en una columna? Se aplica esa misma formula o cambia el procedimiento? Desde ya gracias.

Comment: Se puede trasladar la solución con el `ifelse` a todo el `data.frame`, revisa mi última edición.